# Exact match in strings in python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to find a sub-string in a string, but I am not achieving the results I want.

I have several strings that contains the direction to different directories:

```
'/Users/mymac/Desktop/test_python/result_files_Sample_8_11/logs', 
'/Users/mymac/Desktop/test_python/result_files_Sample_8_1/logs', 
'/Users/mymac/Desktop/test_python/result_files_Sample_8_9/logs'
```

Here is the part of my code here I am trying to find the exact match to the sub-string:

```
 for name in sample_names:

        if (dire.find(name)!=-1): 

            for files in os.walk(dire):

                for file in files:
                    list_files=[]
                    list_files.append(file)
                    file_dict[name]=list_files
```

Everything works fine except that when it looks for Sample_8_1 in the string that contains the directory, the if condition also accepts the name Sample_8_11. How can I make it so that it makes an exact match to prevent from entering the same directory more than once?

Comment: `os.walk()` returns 3 values, not 1 as in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try searching for `sample_8_1/` (i.e., include the following slash).  I guess given your code that would be `dire.find(name+'/')`.  This just a quick and dirty approach.

Comment: Wouldn't this append the slash to the end of each entry? Like `'/Users/mymac/Desktop/test_python/result_files_Sample_8_11/logs/'` and therefor not work?

Comment: Not if I understand the post correctly.  It looks like each element of `sample_names` is a string like `Sample_8_1` representing the substring he wants to find.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `dire` is populated with absolute path names

```
for name in sample_names:
    if name in dire:
        ...
```

e.g.

```
samples = ['/home/msvalkon/work/tmp_1',
           '/home/msvalkon/work/tmp_11']

dirs = ['/home/msvalkon/work/tmp_11']

for name in samples:
    if name in dirs:
        print "Entry %s matches" % name

Entry /home/msvalkon/work/tmp_11 matches
```